# Is there a way to merge a collection of duplicated items along with their child collections using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Example classes:

```
public class Pallet
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Given this input:

```
var input = new List<Pallet>
{
    new Pallet
    {
        Id = 1,
        Locations = new List<Location>
        {
            new Location { Id = 1 },
            new Location { Id = 3 }
        }
    },
    new Pallet
    {
        Id = 2,
        Locations = new List<Location>
        {
            new Location { Id = 2 }
        }
    },
    new Pallet
    {
        Id = 1,
        Locations = new List<Location>
        {
            new Location { Id = 1 },
            new Location { Id = 4 }
        }
    },
};
```

Is there a nice LINQ way to collapse duplicates (in both parent and children collections) to the equivalent of this?

```
var output = new List<Pallet>
{
    new Pallet
    {
        Id = 1,
        Locations = new List<Location>
        {
            new Location { Id = 1 },
            new Location { Id = 3 },
            new Location { Id = 4 }
        }
    },
    new Pallet
    {
        Id = 2,
        Locations = new List<Location>
        {
            new Location { Id = 2 }
        }
    }
};
```

[image: debugger]

Yes, I can iterate over the collection and manually merge items, but I'm curious if LINQ would/can offer something more expressive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this one nice enough?

```
var output = from p in input
             group p by p.Id into g
             select new Pallet
             {
                 Id = g.Key,
                 Locations = (from l in g.SelectMany(x => x.Locations)
                              group l by l.Id into gl
                              select new Location { Id = gl.Key }).ToList()
             };
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `GroupBy` to gather the matching IDs together, then a `Select` to create new collections:

```
var output = input.GroupBy(pallet => pallet.Id)
    .Select(grp => new Pallet {
        Id = grp.Key,
        Locations = grp.SelectMany(pallet => pallet.Locations).Distinct().ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

The one catch to the above, is that [`Distinct()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx) only works correctly on class types, if you either provide it with an `IEqualityComparer<Location>`, or have the "Location" class implement `IEquatable<Location>` (and also override `object.GetHashCode`):

```
public class Location : IEquatable<Location>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Location other)
    {
        //Check whether the compared object is null.  
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(other, null)) return false;

        //Check whether the compared object references the same data.  
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;

        return Id == other.Id;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Or, instead of all that jazz, you could just use a second `GroupBy` at select the first location in each group:

```
var output = input.GroupBy(pallet => pallet.Id)
    .Select(grp => new Pallet {
        Id = grp.Key,
        Locations = grp.SelectMany(pallet => pallet.Locations)
            .GroupBy(location => location.Id)
            .Select(location => location.First())
            .ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort you put in to describe the option for `Distinct()` with `IEquatable`, but I've given the answer to @MarcinJuraszek since you've arrived at the same place and he slightly pipped you in the time to answer. I've given you an upvote though =)

Comment: @Stajs thanks :)  That `Distinct()` thing has given me trouble, so I wanted to work through it.